# Should we avoid using typed arrays in Kotlin ? If yes, Is there any newer way to replace a typed array in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, typed-arrays

Here is my code where this class is used to inflate a view. 
  I am using *typed array* here. Is there any other way I could write this code 
  without using the *typed array*.

```
 class CalculatorInputView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) :
    RelativeLayout(context, attributeSet) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_calculator_input, 
       this, true)

        //attribute set
        attributeSet.run {
            val typedArray: TypedArray =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attributeSet,
                    R.styleable.CalculatorInputView
                )
            val textResource: String? =
                typedArray.getString(R.styleable.CalculatorInputView_item_text)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any other way I could write this code without using the typed array.

No, since the `TypedArray` class is responsible to contain the attributed values of Android resources.

**However**, you can use the [Android KTX Core extensions](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list#androidxcorecontent) in Kotlin to make it shorter:

```kotlin
context.withStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CalculatorInputView) {
   val textResource = getString(R.styleable.CalculatorInputView_item_text)
}
```

Remember that you need to include them in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
```